# How can I specify the relative path in php?

Tags: php

I have `registration.phtml` file in `src/Mess/View/pages` and `registrationView.php` in `src/Mess/View/Views`. How can i specify the relative path to the `registration.phtml` file in the `registrationView.php` file?
This is code i registrationView.php`

```
class RegistrationView extends View
{
public ValidationAttributes $validation;

public function __construct(Action $registration)
{
    parent::__construct(src/Mess/View/pages/registration.phtml', [
        'registration' => $registration,
    ]);
    $this->validation = $registration->validationAttributes([
        'login',
        'password',
        'passwordRepeat',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'email',
        'phoneNumber',
        'birthDate',
        'gender',
        'avatar',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use `../../` until you reach the root folder of your application?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use the given string in the parent::__construct as a path.

```
parent::__construct(__DIR__ . '/../pages/registration.phtml', [
        'registration' => $registration,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a parse error because of a missing quote, plus the `src` directory is by no means a child of `Views`:

```
src
    Mess
        View
            pages
                registration.phtml
            Views
                registrationView.php
```

My advice is that you don't use relative paths, they're very hard to manage when you start nesting includes. You can use the [`__DIR__` the magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) and the [`dirname()` function](https://www.php.net/dirname) to build absolute paths:

```
echo dirname(__DIR__) . '/pages/registration.phtml';
```

Running this from `src/Mess/View/Views/registrationView.php` will print
`/path/to/project/src/Mess/View/pages/registration.phtml`, which is valid no matter current working directory.

But everything will be easier if you create some utility constants that allow you to forget about relatives paths once and for all, as in:

```
parent::__construct(PROJECT_ROOT . PAGES . 'registration.phtml', [
    'registration' => $registration,
]);
// PROJECT_ROOT is `/path/to/project/`
// PAGES is `pages/`
```

Or just:

```
parent::__construct(PAGES . 'registration.phtml', [
    'registration' => $registration,
]);
// PAGES is `/path/to/project/src/Mess/View/pages/`
```